# Issue with color in listings and line breaks

Tags: listings

In the following example, the listing line break at the first space when the text is colored while it does not when the text is in black:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}

\lstdefinestyle{s}{escapechar={|}, breaklines=false, breakatwhitespace=false}

\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]%
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.95\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=s]

|\color{magenta}magentaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa|
blackkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk kkk kkk kkkkkk kkk kkk kkkkkk kkk kkk

\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{}
\label{label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I force a same behavior for both text ? I tried play with `breaklines` and `breakatwhitespace` listing parameters without being successful. The problem might be linked to adjustbox.

#### EDIT

The purpose to use a `\adjustbox` is to fit the listing to the text width.

Comment: Your text in magenta is in between `espcapechar` which means "escape to LaTeX". So, it's in standard LaTeX, if I can say, and it's wrapped to the line width as usual in LaTeX.

Comment: Remark: Your use of `\adjustbox` is strange since it will change the size of the characters. I would recommend using an environment such as `{quote}` instead.

Comment: In fact the `adjustbox` is used to fit my listing to the text width. This is a silly example but in my real case I have a long line that I don't want to break and I want the full listing to be of the size of the text width. Can  I do something similar with quote ?

Comment: Ah. I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your text in magenta in a `\mbox`... It won't be broken.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstdefinestyle{s}{escapechar={|}, breaklines=false, breakatwhitespace=false}

\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]%
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.95\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=s]

|\color{magenta}\mbox{magentaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa}|
blackkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk kkk kkk kkkkkk kkk kkk kkkkkk kkk kkk

\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{}
\label{label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks for the try but this not exactly what I am looking for. See my other comment.

Comment: Ah... I have changed my answer...